# How do I use FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY in combination with UNION ALL in DB2?

Tags: syntax, db2

See title.
This is what I'm trying:

```
select a.work_order_no 
from (

select work_order_no as work_order_no 
from work_order_line 
where insert_timestamp is not null 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY 

union all

select work_order_no as work_order_no 
from work_order_line 
where insert_timestamp is null 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY 

) as a
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

But it give the following error:

`SQL State: 42601 Vendor Code: -199 Message: [SQL0199] Keyword UNION not expected. Valid tokens: ). Cause . . . . . :   The keyword UNION was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword UNION.  The partial list of valid tokens is ). This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the unexpected keyword.  The error may be earlier in the statement but the syntax of the statement seems to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Examine the SQL statement in the area of the specified keyword.  A colon or SQL delimiter may be missing. SQL requires reserved words to be delimited when they are used as a name. Correct the SQL statement and try the request again.   Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete successfully    Failed statements: 1`

In SQL this concept would work with the 'top 1' syntax. I'm assuming this can also work in DB2 but I'm just doing something wrong with the syntax order?

Comment: Which Db2 platform and version?

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a colleague and luckily he responded rather quickly:

I missed some ()

```
select a.work_order_no 
from (

(select work_order_no as work_order_no 
from work_order_line 
where insert_timestamp is not null 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)

union all

(select work_order_no as work_order_no 
from work_order_line 
where insert_timestamp is null 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY )

) as a
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by your query, if you don't care which row you get you can just as well do: `select work_order_no from work_order_line fetch first 1 rows only`